# How do I downgrade my android software from 5.1 back to 4.4.2 on my Nvidia Shield Portable?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

So I decided to download the new software and I cant stand it. I don't have a computer to plug the device into.  So can and how do I do this?

Comment: Can't stand what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rooted Android device, yes it is possible to downgrade your device. You must have a custom recovery installed on your device that is specifically for your phone model and either a stock ROM of the Android version you wish that is also very specific with your phone model or you could install a  custom ROM (I.e. CyanogenMod). You must then install the ROM by using the custom recovery.

If you don't have a rooted device, I'm afraid it's not possible.